# Efficient way to apply highpass to 1D signal in 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, vectorization

I have a very huge array, and each column is a different signal, is there a way to do this efficiently without using looping as below?

```
in_data=rand(2000,100000);

for j=1:size(in_data,2)
    in_data(:,j)=highpass(in_data(:,j),100,1000);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
in_data = highpass(in_data,100,1000)
```

The [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/highpass.html) reads:

> `y = highpass(x,wpass)` filters the input signal `x` using a highpass filter with normalized passband frequency `wpass` in units of π rad/sample. highpass uses a minimum-order filter with a stopband attenuation of 60 dB and compensates for the delay introduced by the filter. **If `x` is a matrix, the function filters each column independently.**

Emphasis mine. Ergo: it goes columnwise by default.